# Azure bash CLI - fork bomb could affected azure?

Tags: bash, azure, command-line-interface

Could "fork bomb" affected azure from global point of view or are host on which Azure Bash CLI running affected ? I saw that Azure Bash CLI not running on the client side but on the Azure server side. I'm not talking about host which you deploy but on "Azure bash cli"... If you perform below "fork bomb" then session is not available anymore ( Fork bomb - Is a denial-of-service attack..where are all available system resources taken and system will crash)
Question is if this could be performed in loop for example 10 000 times and if are this server on microsoft azure side affected which provide this Azure bash CLI.

How you can by yourself test it and reproduce issue ?

1. Open from Azure portal - Azure bash CLI
2. Write "hostname" command to see hostname which is assigned to the Azure bash CLI
3. Paste the following code into Azure bash CLI - to perform "fork bomb"

`:(){ :|: & };:`

4. Now session is not available anymore because no resources are available as I desribed on the top.
5. Now open new session terminal write "hostname" and you will get new Azure bash CLI but old one is not available anymore because is dead...
6. You will see that new hostname is assaigned. You can now do it in loop how many times you want.

Could this affect:

1. Your server on which Azure bash CLI is running ? - Is there solution implemented to prevent this issue ?
2. Could this affected global Azure bash CLI - If big loop for to many session with unique Azure bash CLI hostname is performed.

Answer (score 0):

1. this has nothing to do with Azure cli. Azure cli is just a binary, its a bash (maybe sh, i dont know) "exploit". I can run Azure Cli in powershell and powershell is not affected by this (or cmd)
2. Azure cloud shell is running in an isolated container, so  all you achieve by doing this - container dies, resources are freed. These containers also have resource constraints on them, so you cannot take down the host
3. you can get banned for this, I assume, this is against the EULA

Comment: Thanks that was my question also on the azure training if this running in the container but I not get answer that is reason why I ask this question. Thanks for answer. That means loop affected nothing ?

Comment: i dont know if it works, i dont want to test if it work. if you say it takes down the container, i guess it does that, but since your bash is in the container, you cant really create a loop. as soon as container goes down, your sessions is closed, so your loop is gone